# Ramda pipe with multiple arguments

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I have a method which requires multiple arguments, and I am trying to set up a ramda pipe to handle it.

Here's an example:

```
const R = require('ramda');
const input = [
  { data: { number: 'v01', attached: [ 't01' ] } },
  { data: { number: 'v02', attached: [ 't02' ] } },
  { data: { number: 'v03', attached: [ 't03' ] } },
]

const method = R.curry((number, array) => {
  return R.pipe(
    R.pluck('data'),
    R.find(x => x.number === number),
    R.prop('attached'),
    R.head
  )(array)
})

method('v02', input)
```

Is there a cleaner way of doing this, especially the `x => x.number === number` part of `filter` and having to call `(array)` at the end of the pipe?

[Here's](http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?%0A%20%20%20%20const%20input%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20data%3A%20%7B%20number%3A%20%27v01%27%2C%20attached%3A%20%5B%20%27t01%27%20%5D%20%7D%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20data%3A%20%7B%20number%3A%20%27v02%27%2C%20attached%3A%20%5B%20%27t02%27%20%5D%20%7D%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20data%3A%20%7B%20number%3A%20%27v03%27%2C%20attached%3A%20%5B%20%27t03%27%20%5D%20%7D%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20const%20method%20%3D%20R.curry%28%28number%2C%20array%29%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20R.pipe%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20R.pluck%28%27data%27%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20R.find%28x%20%3D%3E%20x.number%20%3D%3D%3D%20number%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20R.prop%28%27attached%27%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20R.head%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%29%28array%29%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%29%0A%0A%20%20%20%20method%28%27v02%27%2C%20input%29) a link to the code above loaded into the ramda repl.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way this could possibly be rewritten:

```
const method = R.curry((number, array) => R.pipe(
  R.find(R.pathEq(['data', 'number'], number)),
  R.path(['data', 'attached', 0])
)(array))
```

Here we've replaced the use of `R.pluck` and the anonymous function given to `R.find` with `R.pathEq` given as the predicate to `R.find` instead. Once found, the value can be retrieved by walking down the properties of the object with `R.path`.

It is possible to rewrite this in a point-free manner using `R.useWith`, though I feel readability gets lost in the process.

```
const method = R.useWith(
  R.pipe(R.find, R.path(['data', 'attached', 0])),
  [R.pathEq(['data', 'number']), R.identity]
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think readability could be improved using `pluck` and `prop` instead of `path`. Like this:

```
const method = R.useWith(
  R.pipe(R.find, R.prop('attached')),
  [R.propEq('number'), R.pluck('data')]
);
```

And of course, it's better to use a good name for the function. Like `getAttachedValueByNumber`.