# Please how do i achieve the following using ramda

Tags: functional-programming, ramda.js

I have a random array of numbers 1 to five occurring in ramdom sometimes [1,1,1,1,2,2] etc. I am tasked with finding the value with highest occurrence all the the time regardless. I achieved that in javascript like below using a library called ramda [here](https://ramdajs.com/0.22.1/docs/) . After reading the documentation, i went with a solution like below.

```
// filter out duplication in array that way you can get the uniq represented numbers
const uniqueItems = R.uniq(params);

// use the unique numbers as keys and create a new array of object
 const mappedItemsWithRepresentations = map((a) => ({ color: a, rep: params.filter(b => b === a).length }), uniqueItems);

// and then finally, select the item with highest rep and return it key
const maxRepItem = mappedItemsWithRepresentations.reduce((acc, curr) => acc.rep > curr.rep ? acc : curr, []);

return maxRepItem.key; // gives me the correct value i need
```

However, reading through more in the documentation and going through the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41193805/ramda-pipe-with-multiple-arguments), i realised there is a way i can combine the logic above and simply with ramda. I tried numerous attempt possible and the closest i could get are below.

```
const getMaxRep = curry(pipe(uniq, map((a) => ({ color: a, rep: filter(b => b === a).length })), pipe(max(pathEq("rep")), tap(console.log))));

console.log("Max Rep here", getMaxRep(params));
```

I also tried utilising the reduced feature [here](https://ramdajs.com/0.22.1/docs/#reduced), all to no avail. Please how do i arrange achieve that ? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ramda has R.countBy to get the number of occurrences. You can convert the resulting object of country to pairs [value, count], and then reduce it to find the pair with the highest count:

```js
const { pipe, countBy, identity, toPairs, reduce, maxBy, last, head } = R

const fn = pipe(
  countBy(identity), // count the occurrences 
  toPairs, // convert to pairs of [value, count]
  reduce(maxBy(last), [0, 0]), // reduce to find the maximum occurrence
  head, // get the actual value
  Number, // convert back to an number
)

const arr = [1,1,1,1,2,2]

const result = fn(arr)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

A slight variation on this idea that collects values with the same count to an array. This will handle cases in which the frequency of several items is identical:

```js
const { pipe, countBy, identity, toPairs, invert, reduce, maxBy, last, head, map } = R

const fn = pipe(
  countBy(identity), // count the occurrences 
  invert, // combine all values with the same count
  toPairs, // convert to pairs of [value, count]
  reduce(maxBy(head), [0, 0]), // reduce to find the maximum occurrence
  last, // get the actual values
  map(Number), // convert back to numbers
)

const arr = [1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3]

const result = fn(arr)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

Comment: Plz from the code above, I thought head means get the first value regardless, how does that translate to get the actual value in this case. I am trying to understand the code better.

Comment: The `head` takes the first value from the `["1", 4]` entry, yielding "1".  Then we apply `Number` to turn that back into a number.

Comment: The result of the reduce is ["1", "4"], and we need to 1st item, hence the `head`. And scott was faster :)

Answer (score 2):

nice use case, try this:

```js
const maxReduce = reduce(maxBy(last), [0,0])
const getMaxRep = pipe(countBy(identity), toPairs, maxReduce, head)

console.log(getMaxRep([1,1,1,1,2,2]))
```

countBy is a really nice start, sadly Ramda don't support reduce for object but we can convert to an array of arrays using toPairs function and finish the work.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear to me what it is you're asking for.

But it might be something like this:

```js
const maxRep = pipe (
  countBy (identity),
  toPairs,
  map (zipObj(['color', 'rep'])), 
  reduce (maxBy (prop ('rep')), {rep: -Infinity}),
)

const params = [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 5, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 4, 5, 5, 3, 2, 5, 1, 5, 2]

console .log (
  maxRep (params)
)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js"></script>
<script> const {pipe, countBy, identity, toPairs, map, zipObj, reduce, maxBy, prop} = R </script>
```

We start with a list of values drawn from `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`, occuring in some random, multiply-occuring order.

With `countBy(identity)` we change the original list into something like

```js
{"1": 4, "2": 6, "3": 4, "4": 2, "5": 5}
```

with the counts associated with each entry.

`toPairs` formats that as an array like

```
[["1", 4], ["2", 6], ["3", 4], ["4", 2], ["5", 5]]
```

(You could also use `Object.entries` here.)

Then by calling `map (zipObj (['color', 'rep']))`, we turn this into

```
[{"color": "1", "rep": 4}, {"color": "2", "rep": 6}, ...]
```

Finally, we reduce the result, using `maxBy (prop ('rep'))`, which chooses the one with the maximum rep value.  For the initial value to the max call, we create a dummy object, `{rep: -Infinity}` that will compare less than any in your list.

If you wanted to also keep that final intermediate structure, you could rename that function to `makeReps`, dropping off the last function in the pipeline, and then making a new `maxRep` out of it.

Then you could call

```js
const reps = makeResps (params)
const maxVal = maxRep (reps)
```

and use both.

But all this presupposes that the value with `color` and `rep` properties is what you need.  If you just need the count then the other solutions already here handle that fine.

Comment: That helps a lot sir. Thank your time